# Plone 4.1 Mac Snow Leopard 32-bit install problems

Tags: plone

UPDATED: Took everyone's advice and decided plone.app.registry and 4.1.1 were not the issue, question is, what is? Where can I find the error logs in binary installer?

symptom: can't add content types (under Add New... folders, pages, news items, etc. -- hangs on save, more specifically my portal_factory is unable to validate and move the content to ZODB).

had same issue using both unified (4.1) and binary (4.1) installers

environment: mac book 10.6 Snow Leopard 32-bit

When I run buildout I see no errors:
2012-05-08 18:13:34 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Tue May  8 18:13:34 2012
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8080
2012-05-08 18:14:01 WARNING ZODB.FileStorage Ignoring index for /Applications/Plone/zinstance/var/filestorage/Data.fs
2012-05-08 18:14:27 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests

When I create a new site in Plone, Terminal says: http://pastie.org/3882025

Line 23: 2012-05-08 18:16:01 INFO GenericSetup.plone.app.registry Cannot find registry

Comment: Start your Plone server in foreground mode (bin/instance fg) and tell us what that outputs when you access http://localhost:8080 directly without Apache.

Comment: You're on the completely wrong track with your plone.app.registry idea and plone 4.1.1 is obviously not flawed--many people running it in production. To be able to help you, you need to start the server with the "fg" argument as Martijn said and/or gives us your log from startup to where you're getting issues. The apache log is no help.

Comment: http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.registry/1.0b2?plone=4.1.1

Comment: I did start with fg mode see original question. It seems 4.1.1 only works if you migrate or upgrade an existing instance. You can't use it to create brand new instance. See last comment below where I said Terminal was saying "registry not found" when I create a new site.

Comment: http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.registry/1.0b2

Comment: Your post says nothing about starting with fg. You haven't posted your buildout either. Your logic doesn't make any sense--why would you need an upgrade step if you aren't upgrading. You're worrying too much about warnings in the log and haven't shown any error in the log and your reference to the plone.app.registry plip is completely asinine as the problem. Obviously plone 4.1 is not flawed. I and many other people run it in production with plone.app.registry without problems. So you need to pay more attention to detail and try again.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Cheerful. I do run bin/instance fg everytime I start Plone. I will run it again and paste whatever shows up. I updated my question to leave out plone.app.registry and 4.1.1

Comment: You've posted an incomplete question, jumped to invalid conclusions, and then got upset with the people trying to help you. If you can't see anything odd with `bin/instance fg` then try `bin/instance debug` (the latter doesn't provide a working Plone server, but sometimes shows interesting errors on startup).

Comment: btw, your pastie is inadequate.  We've been asking to see the _complete_ log from startup to when you encounter the problem.  If _you_ knew where the problem occurred, you wouldn't need us, so let us see everything and maybe we can see something that you can't.

Comment: ok, well thanks for not giving up on me. Here is my conmplete log from startup: cpe-76-169-8-230:Plone ambi$ bin/instance fg
2012-05-14 18:46:05 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Mon May 14 18:46:05 2012
 Hostname: 0.0.0.0
 Port: 8080
2012-05-14 18:46:23 WARNING ZODB.blob (11651) Blob dir /Users/ambi/diazo-test/Plone/var/blobstorage/ has insecure mode setting
2012-05-14 18:46:49 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests

Comment: and bin/instance debug: cpe-76-169-8-230:Plone ambi$ bin/instance debug
Starting debugger (the name "app" is bound to the top-level Zope object)
2012-05-14 18:49:53 WARNING ZODB.blob (11676) Blob dir /Users/ambi/diazo-test/Plone/var/blobstorage/ has insecure mode setting
>>>

Comment: I was able to fix the insecure mode setting (now I have no errors on startup):cpe-76-169-8-230:Plone ambi$ chmod 700 var/blobstorage
cpe-76-169-8-230:Plone ambi$ bin/instance fg
2012-05-14 19:03:43 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Mon May 14 19:03:43 2012
 Hostname: 0.0.0.0
 Port: 8080
2012-05-14 19:04:23 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests

Comment: and none in bin/instance debug: cpe-76-169-8-230:Plone ambi$ bin/instance debug
Starting debugger (the name "app" is bound to the top-level Zope object)
>>>

Comment: The only time I can't save is when I see portal_factory in the url, like so: http://localhost:8080/Plone/news/portal_factory/ I can save static text portlets and it doesn't reference portal_factory

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error - that's what happens whenever you start up an instance with a new Data.fs file.  If there's no Data.fs.index, or the .index file is inconsistent with the Data.fs, the existing one is ignored and the index is rebuilt.  It means absolutely nothing on a new install.

There must be more information than this in the log.

Comment: Your apache log is no use either, it just tells us that Zope / Plone didn't respond within the timeout.

Comment: When I create a new Plone site I get this in Terminal:2012-05-07 06:01:18 INFO GenericSetup.plone.app.registry Cannot find registry
2012-05-07 06:01:18 INFO GenericSetup.repositorytool Nothing to import.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by following this post here: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Add-new-Plone-site-creates-site-with-JS-problems-4-1-4-tt7547774.html#a7555663

Basically, had to go to javascript registry, save, empty cache, restart browser, testing in Chrome only.